# CollectionEditor error if collection has null items

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid, collectioneditor

If my array property has null items, then I can't open CollectionEditor from PropertyGrid. I get error with text 'component'. How can I fix it?

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Test[] test { get; set; }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            test = new Test[5];
            test[2] = new Test() { Name = "2" };

            propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = this;
        }
    }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
    public class Test
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Maybe I should override some methods in my custom CollectionEditor, but i don't know which

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends exactly how you want to work around this, but if you just need to exclude the null values, then you can override the default [ArrayEditor](https://learn.microsoft.com/ro-ro/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.arrayeditor) class, something like this;

```
// define the editor on the property
[Editor(typeof(MyArrayEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public Test[] test { get; set; }

...

public class MyArrayEditor : ArrayEditor
{
    public MyArrayEditor(Type type) : base(type)
    {
    }

    protected override object[] GetItems(object editValue)
    {
        // filter on the objects you want the array editor to use
        return base.GetItems(editValue).Where(i => i != null).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: So I can't add or remove items. I get message 'Collection was of a fixed size' even if collection has no null items

Comment: @KageBunshin - You talked about CollectionEditor in your question, but you can use ArrayEditor instead